# VB 2010: ScrollToCaret won't work on plain textbox but will with rich text box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, textbox, scroll

I have written an application in VB 2010 that generates log files, and I wanted to add a feature to view the log files without leaving the app. This was done, naturally, by adding a form with a text box and loading in the file.

Sometimes these files get plenty big, so I was looking for a way to just show the most recent entries -- i.e., the last few lines. I got that figured out (using a pretty cool method that works really fast without iterating through all the lines of text).

Just to make it convenient, I wanted to make it display the very bottom of the text box, so ScrollToCaret() was employed. However, in this particular text box, the ScrollToCaret() function didn't work, no matter how I tried to implement it. If I use a RichTextBox, it works fine, and if that's what I need to do, that's how I'll do it. But I have to know why it wouldn't work in a regular text box.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim intLineCount As Int64 = IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFileName).Length
    Dim intStartPosition As Int64 = intLineCount - 1000
    Dim intPositionLoop As Int64
    Try

        Dim strAllLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(strFileName)
        For intPositionLoop = intStartPosition To intLineCount
            txtViewLogs.AppendText(strAllLines(intPositionLoop - 1) & vbNewLine)

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    txtViewLogs.Focus()
    txtViewLogs.ScrollToCaret()
```

As this shows, this will display the last 1000 lines of the log file. When the file is completely loaded, the caret is already at the end of the file, so there was no need to set the `SelectionStart` point to the end of the file, but I even tried that, and no luck.

In order to eliminate the possibility that some property of the text box could have been accidentally changed, I deleted the text box and added another one, taking care not to make any accidental changes to the properties.

Anyone have any idea why it's like this? As I said, if I have to stick with a rich text box, that's what I'll do, but it kills me not knowing why this is doing that. I know I've used this in other applications, but I can't see why it won't work with this one.

Comment: Swallowing exceptions is not a good practice.  Problem isn't reproducible otherwise.  I would avoid calling the ReadAllLines twice like that.  Not sure why you are using Int64 there, just use Integer.

Comment: Well, I'm not quite finished with the code. The exception would not have been ignored entirely. And I used Int64 because I wasn't sure how large that number would be. I thought that plain ol' "int" was a VB6 thing. - Thanks! {UPDATE} VB 2010 doesn't recognize plain ol' 'Int."

Comment: Try just `Integer`.  See `MessageBox.Show(Integer.MaxValue)` to see how big the value is.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behavior. But a little tip: Instead of updating the textbox 1000 times (!), append the text to a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) in the _for loop_.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger - Excellent idea! Thanks! I was pretty proud of myself for discovering the `File.ReadAllLines` trick, loading the text lines into an array and quickly selecting which lines to use. That never showed up in a Google search about viewing the last few lines of the text file. Anyway, it's weird that the ScrollToCaret thing worked ok for you. I must have spent more than an hour on it. Thanks again!